# javahome installer argument (PSSAV)

Tags: java, linux, jdk

Olá, boa noite!
Eu estou precisando instalar o PSSAV para um exercício da faculdade. Porém ele apresenta a caixa de diálogo abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acontece que eu estou com a versão 8 do JDK. A informação que eu posso validar a localização do JDk também não me foi muito clara. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai precisar baixar o JDK 6 do site da Oracle e definir nas suas variáveis de ambiente uma variável chamada JDK_HOME com o caminho para a raiz da pasta que você salvou o JDK e adicionar a JDK_HOME\bin na sua PATH

Existe um tutorial no site da Oracle https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Vai ficar algo como

JDK_HOME = c:\jdk_6

PATH = c:\system32;%JDK_HOME%\bin;